# u-boot and uboot should be synonyms

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

I was just reviewing my old question [How does the bootloader pick up the command after a "restarting system with command"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472761/how-does-the-bootloader-pick-up-the-command-after-a-restarting-system-with-comm/9465314#9465314) and I noticed that my tag [u-boot](/questions/tagged/u-boot) was edited to [uboot](/questions/tagged/uboot).

It seems there are multiple questions under both tags, so I suggest making one a synonym of the other?